# Dataset won't commit to database

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I am a DB programming noob. I need to populate a DB from textbox fields but when I try to then commit it to the DB, I go and view the database and all I see is Nulls... nothing is being saved... please help..

thanks

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TradesDataSet.TradesRow newTradesRow = tradesDataSet.Trades.NewTradesRow();

        newTradesRow.ID = textBoxTradeID.Text; 
        newTradesRow.EntryPrice = textBoxEntryPrice.Text;
        newTradesRow.ExitPrice = textBoxExitPrice.Text;            

        tradesDataSet.Trades.Rows.Add(newTradesRow);
        tradesDataSet.Trades.AcceptChanges();

        try
        {

            this.Validate();
            this.tradesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tradesTableAdapter.Update(this.tradesDataSet.Trades);                
            MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting the ID from a textbox? Shouldn't that be an auto-incrementing field set by the DB?

Comment: Yes. I want to end up doing that. I just can't even get anything to save into the DB first...

Comment: As a tip: DataSets arn' the best way to build a database driven application. I've been there, tried it, and it has so many disadvantages... there is a simpler and better way to deal with database transactions by using the System.Data.SqlClient namesace. it is easier to cotrol the acions and use stored procedures with parameters, making sql transactions, getting daa from the database etc. you should read about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `AcceptChanges` call. Data adapter's `Update` method looks at the changes in the database and uses the change list to update the actual database. It automatically accepts the changes in the `DataSet` after the update. If you call `AcceptChanges` on the `DataSet` manually before updating, the `DataAdapter` will think nothing is changed and doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried that. It still doesn't work... :( Thanks though, I think I'm going to take GxG's advice and checkout SqlClient...

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility. If you have added a database to your project and have set its "Copy to Output Directory" property as "Always", any changes you have made to your database will be reverted as the newer copy gets replaced by the old one.

To prevent this set that property to "Copy if newer" or "Don't copy"

Answer (score 0):

[See ADO.NET: Update a Database from a DataSet;](http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/adoplus/UpdateDataFromDB.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    TradesDataSet.TradesRow newTradesRow = tradesDataSet.Trades.NewTradesRow(); 

    newTradesRow.ID = textBoxTradeID.Text;  
    newTradesRow.EntryPrice = textBoxEntryPrice.Text; 
    newTradesRow.ExitPrice = textBoxExitPrice.Text;             

    tradesDataSet.Trades.Rows.Add(newTradesRow); 
    //Wrong, this command says that what I have in the dataset is what is in 
    //the database.  You only use this if you manually update the dataset in 
    //the background.
    //tradesDataSet.Trades.AcceptChanges(); 

    try 
    { 
        //EndEdit then force a validate.
        this.tradesBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.Validate();  
        //Internally this method calls .AcceptChanges();
        this.tradesTableAdapter.Update(this.tradesDataSet.Trades);                 
        MessageBox.Show("Update successful"); 
    } 
    catch (System.Exception ex) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Update failed"); 
    } 
}
```